# find & delete with regex

Tags: regex, find

how to match then delete files with regex through commandline?

matched files have 4 digits then .tmp eg

```
something0001.tmp
something-else-0090.tmp
something-6548.tmp
```

but not

```
something001.tmp
somethingelse99.tmp
```

tried various versions of

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\d{4}.tmp' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

RegExr testing ok for matches, but ssh syntax is eluding me and am sure the regex is at fault.

Comment: Try double escaping the d `\\d` and escaping the . `\.`

Comment: While playing around with the regexp maybe replace `-exec rm -rf {} \;` with `-exec ls {} \;` :)

Comment: @Michael :) yes am doing the same, but double escaping not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is using by default Emacs syntax of regex. This means that there is nothing like `\d` or `{4}`. You if you want to achieve this result, you need to use (also escape the second dot `.`).

```
find . -type f -regex '.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.tmp' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

or use different `-regextype` option which supports your regex syntax.

Comment: Then how about  find . -name *.tmp | grep -e someRegex |  xargs rm

Comment: @Jakuje - thank you - working a peach - found this excellent reference for situations ahead :

[emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-test/RegularExpression)